# Passing items after .parallel() in runner definition fails

Tags: karate

I recently add the systemProperty attribute to some runners, but uncovered that parallel HAS TO BE the last item in the definition.  Is this by design, or simply something wonky in the code?

The returned error when parallel is not last, for the example image shown below:

`The method karateEnv(String) is undefined for the type ResultsJava(67108964)`

[image: .parallel as last item]
[image: .parallel NOT last item]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - by design, this is explained in the documentation: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#parallel-execution